# How to remove search bar from the blog post

Tags: search

I just started to create my own site, and it's so frustrating, that it makes me want to throw my laptops out of the window.

I have a problem with the search bar. When you open a post, you will see a search bar at the right side. I want to remove it, got any ideas how to do this?

the site: https://anpio.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is added by the theme you are using. And, unless there is an option in theme settings (or customizer) to remove it, you can't do much about it, because you are hosting on WordPress.com, and unless you pay for the premium plan, you can't modify plugins or themes.

Comment: That makes sense.
Okay, so the only solution is to change the theme...
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Most themes on WP.com have search option of some sort, but, find the one that is less intrusive.